# How to retrieve all linkIds, nodeIds, and geometries within a given bounding box using HERE Map API

Tags: geometry, here-api

How can I retrieve all linkIds(PVID), nodeIds, and shapepoints(geometry) based on a given bounding box using HERE Map API (Fleet Telematics Advanced Data Sets)?

Answer (score 0):

Go through our documentation in https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/topics/resource-search-bbox.html to understand Bounding Box search in PDE. You can query each Link_FC1..5 layers for getting link information. Try https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/cle2_pde_search to better understand the output.

A sample query would be like:

```
https://pde.cit.api.here.com/1/search/bbox.json?layer_id=LINK_FC4&bbox=41.91,12.47;41.893,12.51&app_code=xxx&app_id=xxx&key_attribute=LINK_ID
```

Comment: Documentation was not clear enough to understand how to get those information. I use the following parameters in the PDE search which didn't give me back anything: endpoint(https://pde.api.here.com/1/tile.json), searchtype(boundingbox), app_id(my_own), app_code(my_own), MapLayer(ROAD_GEOM_FC1), KeyAttribute(LINK_ID), Label(none), SearchParameters(bbox=41.904,-87.682;41.853,-87.619). This is not working.

Comment: Could you let me know what endpoint and which parameters I have to use for the query?

Comment: Updated the answer for the exact query.